# Pack Kivy Application with Pyinstaller - AttributeError

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I previously packed apps successfully with Kivy and PyInstaller. My Kivy code has changed quite a bit, and now it seems like I can not successfully run my built project anymore due to the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "GUI.py", line 33, in <module>
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
   File "kivy\__init__.py", line 297, in <module>
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'load_module'
[8640] Failed to execute script 'GUI' due to unhandled exception!
```

A little bit of background: GUI is my main class, the application files are within a folder GUI_T3 and i also add a couple of files via `--add-data` which are not in that folder. Also, i have my build-scripts inside a folder called BUILD, which is parallel to the GUI_T3 folder. I use --hidden-import for `kivy_deps.sdl2` and `kivy_deps.glew`. The above error happens after trying to run my GUI.exe. The command i use for creating this package is the following:

```
pyinstaller --clean --noconfirm --icon=../GUI_T3/static/icon_small.ico --name "T3 Navigator" --add-data ../GUI_T3/GUI.ini;. --add-data ../GUI_T3/navigator.ini;. --add-data ../GUI_T3/static;./static --add-data ../GUI_T3/library;./library --add-data ../GUI_T3/layouts;./layouts --add-data ../../fpga/register_map/pico_regs.json;. --hidden-import kivy_deps.sdl2 --hidden-import kivy_deps.glew ../GUI_T3/GUI.py
```

After this initial build i modify my created .spec file to correctly process kivy_deps.sdl2, kivy_deps.glew and kivy_deps.gstreamer (this worked previously, even though i did not add gstreamer as a hidden import compared to sdl2 and glew) ([Link to my .spec file](https://textuploader.com/tacw2)):

```
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew, gstreamer
...
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('..\\GUI_T3\\'),
               ...
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins + gstreamer.dep_bins)],
               ...)
```

To create the package, i first created a virtual environment to make sure i have all the dependencies covered, created a requirements file ([Link to my requirements.txt](https://textuploader.com/tacwv)) just to be sure, and afterwards ran the pyinstaller command from within the virtual environment: `pyinstaller "T3 Navigator.spec" --clean --noconfirm`

I tested re-arranging my kivy imports in my GUI.py file, and it seems like the AttributeError is thrown at the line where i first import any kivy module. So the GUI works fine when running it via a VENV, but does not after packing it trying to execute the .exe file. Am i missing something? I cant get behind whats going wrong .. The only difference i can think of right now is that i did not use kivymd and use Config.read() at the beginning of my code to read a config file compared to my last project where everything worked.

Comment: Thank you for sharing detailed information, so far it seems that kivy plus a few modules cannot or does not add itself into you App or Program (maybe), one thing you could do is if the Program has packaged itself succesfully, you can uncompress it later to review if kivy deps and other modules are added into the internal site packages needed, plus in some cases when building a package the way you are doing it with pyinstaller the propieties in the functions inside of the spec file, are really sensitive and one more number increased maynot create a working App but is about the bundle itself

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jbsidisJosuéCarranza :) so you recommend to verify if all my dependencies (e.g. kivy, pandas, cv2, ..) are copied correctly in my dist folder? Or how should i do your suggestion "uncompress it later to review if kivy deps and other modules.." ? Thanks alot for taking your time already

Comment: I just tried to create the pyinstaller-package with an older virtual environment and it worked - seems like my problem is related to some newer version of some dependency. I will try to investigate and find out whats going wrong

Comment: That's great, I'm glad to hear you fixed the issue, yeah probably something about the dependencies throws errors but yeah, I hope you find the best solution